# Combine two objects in react, no success so far

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, react-hooks

I'm trying to combine two object together without any luck...
I'm using the spread operator as you should in es6. I'm pretty sure it has something to do with useState. I will start by showing you the console.logs from my objects then the code :)

**CONSOLE.LOGS**

Object #1:

[image: Object #1]

Object #2:

[image: Object #2]

After combining the objects and logging the combined result I only get Object #1 like this:

[image: Combined Object]

**MY CODE**

```
const PortfolioComponent = () => {

const [clickedElement, setClickedElement] = useState({})
const [stockObject, setStockObject] = useState({})
const [stockData, setStockData] = useState({})

const getStock = () => {
    axios.request(stock)
    .then( res => {
      console.log("2. Object #2 from API: ", res.data)
      setStockData(res.data) // HERE I SET THE OBJECT FROM MY API CALL
    })
    .catch( error => {
      console.error(error);
  }

  const handleOpen = name => { // In this function i call the api function and combine the two objects.
    
    let findClickedStock = props.stocksArray.find(item => item.ticker === name)
    setClickedElement(findClickedStock)
    getStock();
    console.log("1. Object #1: ", findClickedStock)

    setTimeout(() => { // Waitning for the api to fetch
      setStockObject({...findClickedStock, ...stockData}) // Here i combine the two objects, no success
      console.log("3. Combined object - Only gets Object #1...", stockObject)
    }, 2000);

    setOpen(true);
  };
 
}

export default PortfolioComponent;
```

Comment: Do you get the same results if you log `{...findClickedStock, ...stockData}` directly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)

Comment: you dont need to use setTimeout for waiting api result. Just return a promise from getStock and it in handler like getStock().then(res => {...});

Comment: @poltorin I know I can do that but cant figure out how really, so this is a fast resulotion :p
Can you show me how i can proceed?

Comment: @gospecomid12 added an answer below

Comment: @TedBrownlow Yes I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const getStock = () => {
  return axios.request(stock)
  .then( res => res.data)
  .catch( error => {
    console.error(error);
}

const handleOpen = name => { // In this function i call the api function and combine the two objects.
  
  let findClickedStock = props.stocksArray.find(item => item.ticker === name)
  setClickedElement(findClickedStock)

  console.log("1. Object #1: ", findClickedStock)

  getStock().then((dataFromStockApi) => {
    setStockObject({ ...dataFromStockApi, ...findClickedStock });
  });

  setOpen(true);
};
```

Comment: Now everything works, just had to add a return before res.data in my api call :D
Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Hooks API Reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate):

*Note
Unlike the setState method found in class components, useState does not automatically merge update objects. You can replicate this behavior by combining the function updater form with object spread syntax:*

```js
setState(prevState => {
  // Object.assign would also work
  return {...prevState, ...updatedValues};
});
```

Also, check out `useReducer` which is generally recommended for managing state with multiple sub-values.